# Failed to create project-maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

Hi i am new to spring and hibernate. I am trying to create a maven project in eclipse. But while trying to create its showing an error like "Failed to create project. java.lang.NullPointerException"
 [Please find the attached error message image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfz39.png)

How to resolve this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Eclipse has an error log; look there for a more detailed error, and update your question with it.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the reply.. Now its working fine